# Is it correct to assume that if $n \in \mathbf{Z}_+$ then $ \Big|\frac{\sin(n)}{2^n}\Big| \leq \Big|\frac{1}{2^n}\Big|$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I am always wary of making mistakes when dealing with trigonometric functions and ratios, but I believe that it makes sense to say that
$$
|\sin(n)| \leq 1 \implies \frac{1}{2^n}|\sin(n)| \leq \frac{1}{2^n} \implies \Big|\frac{\sin(n)}{2^n}\Big| \leq \Big|\frac{1}{2^n} \Big|
$$
Is there anything invalid with this line of reasoning?

Comment: Perfectly valid. There is no need for absolute value on RHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong and $n$ can be any real number also.